# Firebase multiple accounts in the same session

Tags: javascript, web, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to add users for website login using firebase authentication simultaneously as Google does using url parameters as

.../user/0
../user/1

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple `FirebaseApp` instances in your project, and each of those can have its own signed in user.

See the documentation [configuring multiple projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects), although in this case you'd configure the same project multiple times.

So something along the lines of:

```
var config = {
  apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
  authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
  storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
};
var app1 = firebase.initializeApp(config);
var app2 = firebase.initializeApp(config);

app1.auth().signIn...
app2.auth().signIn...
```